# Weka Multilayer Perceptron incremental learning

Tags: java, classification, weka, perceptron

I am using weka multilayer perceptron to build my classifier. The thing is, I have so many datasets so I want to do a incremental training over and over again. After I call buildClassifier with dataset1. After I finished the training, What if I call buildClassifier with dataset2. What will happen? Is the network I have already trained with database1 getting lost? Or the starting point the next time I call builderClassifier(dataset2) is the trained network with dataset1? If it is the first case, is there a way I can do as what I said using weka MLP?

Also, if I am not passing seed to MLP, I am guessing the network will always return me the same initial weight since the default seed is 0.

Thanks!

Comment: Show, share your codes to people can understand you better than give you the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't learn a MultilayerPerceptron incrementally, every time you call buildClassifier method on the same classifier instance you will overwrite the current model with the new one.

If you want the learning process to use more samples just add them to the training set (dataset1) and start a new learning process calling buildClassifier on the new dataset, so that the back propagation algorithm can use all the available data to train the model!

On the other hand, if you have trained a model with, say, 10 epochs and you want to train another model on the same dataset but with 20 epochs, without losing the first one, you can simply copy it with the method makeCopy().

See the doc for more informations: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable-3-8/weka/classifiers/functions/MultilayerPerceptron.html